# Cache region configurations in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, persistence, infinispan

According to **[this documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_jboss_as_and_wildfly)**, when using **Infinispan** with Hibernate it is possible to define multiple cache regions and configure them individually. I'm using **WildFly 8.0**, which uses Infinispan as a default 2LC provider for Hibernate. So here's my standalone.xml configuration for hibernate cache container:

```xml
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
    <local-cache name="entity">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="local-query">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="timestamps">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

So, the max idle expiration time is set to 100 seconds. This is how I tell Hibernate to cache query:

```java
slotQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
         .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheRegion", "myRegionName")
         .getResultList();
```

Everything is working perfeclty, the queries are being cached for 100 seconds. But when I'm trying to configure a separate cache region for the query in persistence.xml:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.myRegionName.expiration.max_idle" value="5000"/>
```

settings are not being overriden, and the query is cached for 100 seconds. What am I missing here?

Comment: When running inside the application server, deployment name needs to be added, i.e. `hibernate.cache.infinispan.<warname>.<unitname>.<FQN of entity>.expiration.max_idle`. Can you try this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Galder Zamarreño in the comments, the deployment name has to be added to the region.

Or, you can explicitly set `prefix` to empty ("") or some value like below.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="my-cache"/>
```

And then specify the region `prefix` as below.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.my-cache.myRegionName.expiration.max_idle" value="5000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put in your persistence.xml the factory_class:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />
```

The value 5000 is really what you want ? Remember that this is in milliseconds, so your cache max idle is set to 5 seconds.

Regarding the cacheRegion, i couldn't find a way to create one costumized for queries. It is possible to overwrite the infinispan default though. You could use the default query cache region to configure the max_idle, this way:

```
<!-- entity cache, never expires = -1 -->
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle"
            value="-1" />
<!-- query cache, with 12 hours expiration -->
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.query.expiration.max_idle"
            value="1620000" />
```